# Gitlab Ci Pipeline issue: Nodejs can't connect to Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, node.js, gitlab-ci, pipeline, typeorm

I'm trying to set up a Gitlab Ci Pipeline where i can test my nodejs app. The problem is, that app can't connect to the Database. I tried to configure everthing like [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/mysql.html). I dont really know why it can't find the Database and haven't found any other examples or sources for that. The problem is, that the app needs the db to run, otherwise it stopps.

For the Database connection im using typeorm:

```
"type": "mysql",
   "host": "db",
   "port": 3306,
   "username": "root",
   "password": "logistics",
   "database": "logistics",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": true,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
```

this is my gitlab.yml :

```
# https://hub.docker.com/r/library/node/tags/
image: node:13

variables:
  # Configure mysql environment variables (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_DATABASE: "logistics"
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "logistics"
  MYSQL_USER: "paramedic"
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: "logistics"
  MYSQL_PORT: "3306"
  
# Check out: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-a-service
services:
  - name: mysql:5.7
  
# http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cache
cache:
  paths:
    - backend/node_modules/

test_backend:
  script:
    - cd backend/
    - yarn install
    - yarn start
```

This is the error Message:

```
$ yarn start
 yarn run v1.22.4
 warning package.json: No license field
 $ ts-node-dev --project=tsconfig.json --transpileOnly --respawn src/index.ts
 Using ts-node version 8.10.2, typescript version 3.9.2
 Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db
     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26)
     --------------------
     at Protocol._enqueue (/builds/stjorueh/rettungsdienstverwalter/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
     at Protocol.handshake (/builds/stjorueh/rettungsdienstverwalter/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
     at PoolConnection.connect (/builds/stjorueh/rettungsdienstverwalter/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
     at Pool.getConnection (/builds/stjorueh/rettungsdienstverwalter/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
     at /builds/stjorueh/rettungsdienstverwalter/backend/src/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.ts:884:18
     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
     at MysqlDriver.createPool (/builds/stjorueh/rettungsdienstverwalter/backend/src/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.ts:881:16)
     at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/builds/stjorueh/rettungsdienstverwalter/backend/src/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.ts:343:36)
     at step (/builds/stjorueh/rettungsdienstverwalter/backend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:139:27)
     at Object.next (/builds/stjorueh/rettungsdienstverwalter/backend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:120:57) {
   errno: -3008,
   code: 'ENOTFOUND',
   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
   hostname: 'db',
   fatal: true
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `mysql` as a DB host, not `db`. You can read explanation here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-services-are-linked-to-the-job

Alternatively, you can specify alias for mysql service

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem. After that i got a connection refused Error but i just had to put a timer for the Server to sleep for 20sec so that the db can start up